# Install python module without PIP

Tags: python, windows, module, installation

I downloaded a python module(wx) from repository. Now, how to I install manually in windows instead of using pip. Downloaded file is "wx-3.0.3.tar.gz". After extraction where do I kept the files within python installation directory?

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot use pip?

Comment: I tried to install it in my office. I am not able to do there. I don't know why. Via browser the repository open properly, but while using pip it makes problem.

Comment: Did you try downloading the .exe file from [here](https://wxpython.org/download.php)?