# how to load pip-installed module from sublimetext?

Tags: python-3.x, import, pip, sublimetext3

I installed `recordclass` via `pip3 install recordclass` which installs it under `/Users/timothee/homebrew/lib/python3.7/site-packages/recordclass`; I'm trying to use it from a sublimetext package but it fails:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('/Users/timothee/homebrew/lib/python3.7/site-packages')
import recordclass
ImportError: No module named 'recordclass.mutabletuple'
```

If I instead use `sys.path.append('/Users/timothee/homebrew/lib/python3.7/site-packages/recordclass')` I get: `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`

Note that it does work for some other pip3 installed modules, eg `jstyleson`, `simplejson`.

Here is contents of recordclass:

```
\ls
__init__.py                             arrayclass.py                           datatype.py                             mutabletuple.cpython-37m-darwin.so      recordobject.cpython-37m-darwin.so      test                                    utils.py
__pycache__                             dataobject.cpython-37m-darwin.so        litelist.cpython-37m-darwin.so          recordclass.py                          structclass.py                          typing
```

Not sure whether the reason is that sublime bundles its own python interpreter (3.3 IIRC) and my system python is 3.7, and it installs as `recordobject.cpython-37m-darwin.so` so can't be seen by sublime's python; but temporarily renaming to `recordobject.cpython-33m-darwin.so` didn't help.

Note: I've read other similar questions but these didn't help, eg:
* [Install python module without PIP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756230/install-python-module-without-pip) => not relevant; I can install it; just not load it from sublime
* [Installing python modules like "Web3" without pip/pip3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57039987/installing-python-modules-like-web3-without-pip-pip3) ditto
* https://github.com/SublimeText/UnitTesting/issues/67

This is the most relevant post: [Sublime Plugin: How can I import wx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29250870/sublime-plugin-how-can-i-import-wx) but the solution there doesn't seem to work; since the problem seems to be these `darwin.so` files in my case

Comment: "I'm trying to use it from a sublimetext package"  – does this mean you're *developing* a Sublime Text package (as in plugin) which relies on a third-party module?

Comment: it's for customizing my sublime text editor, not necessarily meant for publishing it as a sublime text package, so I'm ok with any dirty hacks so long it works

Comment: The version of Python that Sublime uses is 3.3.6; the ABI changes when the version of Python changes, so any package with byte code or native code will only work if it was compiled for python 3.3.6. There are a few ways you can get external modules to be seen in Sublime (modifying the `sys.path` or dropping them into the Sublime `DATA` directory at `Lib/python3.3`) but if the module has an external library or compiled byte code, you're likely out of luck.